# Laravel how to create filter by date for table

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

so I made an update to my table so the user can search the data filtered by date (year), by adding a drop down menu for the selection. I'm trying to use **ajax** to filter the date, but somehow I can't get it to work. May I know what is wrong with my code? Or is there another way to filter my table by date?

**Blade file for the table view**

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Tabel Pekerjaan</h3>
                  <br>
                  <div class="card-tools">
                    <a href="/tambahpekerjaan" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp Tambah Pekerjaan</a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <select id="filter-tahun" class="form-control filter">
                        <option value="">Pilih Tahun</option>
                        @foreach ($pekerjaan as $pekerjaans)
                          <option value="{{$pekerjaans->id}}">{{$pekerjaans->tanggal}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                  <table id="tabelpekerjaan" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10px">No.</th>
                        <th>Paket Pekerjaan</th>
                        <th>Tanggal</th>
                        <th>Nama Perusahaan</th>
                        <th>Lokasi Pekerjaan</th>
                        <th>PPK</th>
                        <th>HPS</th>
                        <th>Gambar</th>
                        <th style="width: 120px">Aksi</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @php $no = 1; @endphp
                      @foreach ($pekerjaan as $pekerjaans)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                        <td>{{$pekerjaans->pekerjaan}}</td>
                        <td>{{$pekerjaans->tanggal}}</td>
                        <td>{{$pekerjaans->penyedia->nama}}</td>
                        <td>{{$pekerjaans->lokasi}}</td>
                        <td>{{$pekerjaans->user->name}}</td>
                        <td>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaans->hps,0,',',',')}}</td>
                        <td>
                          <img src="{{asset('gambarpekerjaan/'.$pekerjaans->gambar)}}" style="width: 100px"alt="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Auth::user()->status=='super')
                              <a href="/editpekerjaan/{{$pekerjaans->id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
                              <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete" data-id="{{$pekerjaans->id}}" data-nama="{{$pekerjaans->pekerjaan}}">Hapus</a>
                            @else
                            <a href="/editpekerjaan/{{$pekerjaans->id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Edit</a>
                              
                            @endif
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.card -->
  
            
    </div>
</section>
```

**here is the script**

```
<script>
  
  $(function () {
    // let pekerjaan = $("#filter-tahun").val();
    
    /*const table =*/ $('#tabelpekerjaan').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
      "responsive": true,
      // "ajax":{
      //   url: "{{url('')}}/datapekerjaan",
      //   type:"POST",
      //   data:function(d){
      //     d.pekerjaan = pekerjaan;
      //     return d
      //   }
      // }
    });

    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2bs4').select2({
      theme: 'bootstrap4'
    })
  });

  
  @if (session()->has('message'))
    toastr.success("{{session()->get('message')}}")  
  @endif

  $('.delete').click(function(){
    var idpekerjaan = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var namapekerjaan = $(this).attr('data-nama');

    Swal.fire({
  title: 'Apakah Anda yakin?',
  text: "Paket Pekerjaan "+namapekerjaan+" akan dihapus!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Ya, yakin!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    window.location = "/deletepekerjaan/"+idpekerjaan+""
    Swal.fire(
      'Dihapus!',
      'Data berhasil dihapus.',
      'success'
    )
  }
});
  });

  // $(".filter").on('change',function(){
  //   pekerjaan = $("#filter-tahun").val()
  //   table.ajax.reload(null,false)
  // })
</script>
```

I commented on the ajax's part since it doesn't work at all and my table become a mess...

May I know how to resolve this problem? Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This

> $(document).ready(function () {
> // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
> $('#example thead tr')
> .clone(true)
> .addClass('filters')
> .appendTo('#example thead');
>
> ```
> var table = $('#example').DataTable({
>     orderCellsTop: true,
>     fixedHeader: true,
>     initComplete: function () {
>         var api = this.api();
>
>         // For each column
>         api
>             .columns()
>             .eq(0)
>             .each(function (colIdx) {
>                 // Set the header cell to contain the input element
>                 var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
>                     $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
>                 );
>                 var title = $(cell).text();
>                 $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
>
>                 // On every keypress in this input
>                 $(
>                     'input',
>                     $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
>                 )
>                     .off('keyup change')
>                     .on('change', function (e) {
>                         // Get the search value
>                         $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
>                         var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();
>
>                         var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
>                         // Search the column for that value
>                         api
>                             .column(colIdx)
>                             .search(
>                                 this.value != ''
>                                     ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
>                                     : '',
>                                 this.value != '',
>                                 this.value == ''
>                             )
>                             .draw();
>                     })
>                     .on('keyup', function (e) {
>                         e.stopPropagation();
>
>                         $(this).trigger('change');
>                         $(this)
>                             .focus()[0]
>                             .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
>                     });
>             });
>     },
> }); });
> ```

Refer This https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But what I need is a drop down menu whereby when you click it will show the data corresponding with the year... For the search method I already did it and the end user need the drop down menu,,,

Comment: This ?? https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: Yes like that, but how to make it show only unique year, in the example it shows the entire list of date, but I only need the year (unique).... May I know how to solve it?

Comment: For that you can try pass year as a column and hide the same and use filter .example above shows only unique cities